# How to fix in pagination, My function will not work properly Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I‘m using pagination in my App, Data is coming from server. When I use call the function and reload tableView, It‘ll not shown any changes in my tableview.

When show data, without using pagination, It works perfectly. But with pagination, A lot of error comes.

**ViewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentUserImage()
    activityShown()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

}
```

**Refresh**

```
@objc func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    activityArray.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()
    activityShown()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

**Pagination**

```
  func activityShown() {
current_page = current_page + 1
let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")!)"]
//----------------------  Alamofire for User Profile ---------------------//
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "per_page": per_page,
    "page": current_page
]
Alamofire.request(Constants.activitiesURL,method: .get, parameters: parameters,  encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        let ActivityJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
        let activityData = ActivityJSON["data"].arrayValue
        for value in activityData {
            let activity = Activity()
            activity.name = value["name"].stringValue
            activity.content = value["content"].stringValue
            activity.published = value["published"].stringValue
            activity.thumbnail = value["users"]["photo_thumb"].stringValue
            activity.likesCount = value["likes_count"].intValue
            activity.liked = value["liked"].intValue
            activity.heartCount = value["heart_count"].intValue
            activity.hearted = value["hearted"].intValue
            activity.commentsCount = value["comments_count"].intValue
            activity.commented = value["commented"].intValue
            activity.id = value["id"].intValue
            activity.currentID = value["users"]["user_id"].intValue
            print("Like \(activity.liked!)")
            print("heart \(activity.hearted!)")
            self.activityArray.append(activity)
        }
        self.Total_activities = ActivityJSON["meta"]["pagination"]["total"].intValue
        self.pCount = ActivityJSON["meta"]["pagination"]["count"].intValue
        self.per_page = ActivityJSON["meta"]["pagination"]["per_page"].intValue
        self.current_page = ActivityJSON["meta"]["pagination"]["current_page"].intValue
        self.total_pages = ActivityJSON["meta"]["pagination"]["total_pages"].intValue
        //                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        //                            }
    }
    else {
        print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
    }
}
}
```

This is my function. and the output because of this is, when I refresh the tableView. It didn't refresh the tableView

Comment: Please, provide more details.

Comment: first remove activityArray.removeAll() and then check when you reload tableview in activityShown function please check your activityArray is updated with new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is about you commented out your main thread code. You need to call `reloadData()` method inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Also, problem could be when you called `endRefreshing` method your `refresh` method is called and inside of that method you are removing all the elements inside `activityArray`.

Comment: Even if your code is not working every UI changes should be wrapped in main thread.

Comment: What should I have to do ?

Comment: You should not remove all the array elements inside `refresh` method.

Comment: ` @objc func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
        activityShown()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }`

Comment: Sorry, these are the only things that I can suggest. I recommend you to put a debug breakpoint and observe your array.

Answer (score 0):

Write these two lines after appending data in your array.

In response.result.isSuccess block

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

Comment: Why to block that ?

Comment: Did you try that ?

Comment: Sorry the main thing is . Remove activityArray.removeAll() this line in refersh data . Then you will see your appending data

Comment: As you remove data from array after refresh it remove previous data and you hit api call for next page . Maybe next page doesn't have data so it empty array will be shown to you.

Comment: Did you try after remove that line ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the below line from `refresh(sender:)` method,

```
activityArray.removeAll()
```

Since in *pagination*, you're appending elements in `activityArray`, there is no need to remove the previously fetched data.

With the above line, pagination won't work as expected because the `activityArray` will only contain the newly fetched `activities`.

There is even no need for `refresh(sender:)` method. You can directly add `activityShown()` to `refreshControl's` `selector`, i.e.

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activityShown), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

You can simply call `tableView.reloadData()` and `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` after the data is fetched, i.e.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```